# How do I install Google Chrome dev version?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I want to install Google Chrome Nightly (the dev version) next to the stable version. Is there a PPA for Nightly and 12.04?

[These](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/dev) are the only PPAs I found and they are not working on 12.04 yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download Google Chrome's dev version here:

http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Do note that Google Chrome's binaries automatically add the repositories. So, you will receive updates as and when Google Chrome's dev version is updated.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to install it side by side with the stable version? When trying to install the dev version it cancels and tells me that it collides with the stable version.

Comment: @dotweb Side by side? No, that is not possible.

Comment: What a pity. :(

Comment: As an aside, the dev version is not the same as a nightly and is not the same as canary.  Canary is more up to date than dev...

Comment: @jmort253 The OP mentioned dev version inside the question. I followed that.. And there is no canary version outside of Windows.

Comment: @dotweb While you can't get multiple systemwide installations of Chrome by installing multiple `.deb` packages, you can (last I tried it, which was a few weeks ago), have both Chrome and Chromium installed. The Chromium packages in Ubuntu are version from which stable Chrome builds have been made. (Ubuntu's official Chromium packages often lag behind the latest stable, however.)